# Can an Indian Muslim legally migrate to Pakistan?

Tags: citizenship, indian-citizens, india, pakistani-citizen

Kashmir has been an unrelenting problem. In addition to that, there have been a lot of incidents nowadays under BJP rule in India.

Can Indian Muslims legally migrate to Pakistan, if they want to?

Comment: Because the political and diplomatic relations between Pakistan and India are complicated and fraught, you should contact a Pakistani solicitor. Avoid "advisors" and "counselors" and other unlicensed individuals.